# Having past participle

Tags: american-english, british-english

Am I correct in thinking that `having + past participle` conveys the flowing meaning?

Pharse:

> Tomorrow, having finished the game, I will go home.

Means:

> Tomorrow, after finishing the game, I will go home.

Comment: Yes that's correct but but you can't use **i**.  It's always used in capital as a pronoun

Comment: @Ziyabano: Sorry to interrupt, but can we interpret 'Tomorrow, having finished the game, I will go home' as 'Tomorrow, since I have finished the game, I will go home.'?

Comment: Yeah. I think your two sentences are equivalent in meaning. You could also say, "Tomorrow, after having finished the game, I will go home." That also means the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The former is a little confusing. A proficient English speaker will still understand you, but the exact cause-and-effect relationships are unclear.

The `having + past participle` construction is properly used in the past tense:

```
Yesterday, having finished the game, I went home.
```

This means that some time yesterday, I finished the game, and then I went home. The sentence would still make sense without the "yesterday"; it just adds some detail.

By saying `Tomorrow, having finished the game`, you're applying a purely past construction to the future tense. There are constructs for this scenario, and your second sentence is one of them, but "Tomorrow, having finished" is not.

---

Regarding your second sentence, `Tomorrow, after I finish the game, I will go home` would be a little better. It confuses readers/listeners for a moment to read/hear what the subject (I) is doing before learning who/what the subject is.

Answer (score 0):

The sentences do mean the same thing.  (I'd expect to hear "After I finish the game tomorrow, I'll go home," but all 3 sentences mean the same thing.)